# Compare value of a column with multiple values from other column

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hope, you will help me to figure out a good solution.
I have to build folder tree, retreiving data from MYSQL table first. Simplified structure of my table called `categories` is:

```
id parent_id name
1  0         jackets
2  0         sweaters
3  1         men
4  1         woomen
5  0         trousers
6  5         children
```

To build it correctly(javascript, styles) i have to determine, whether current category has or has not children, by comparing value of column 'id' with the values from all the rows of the column 'parent_id', so there should be dynamic column has_children.

Output has to be like this:

```
id parent_id name     has_children
1  0         jackets  true
2  0         sweaters false
3  1         men      false
4  1         woomen   false
5  0         trousers true
6  5         children false
```

Comment: Note that by convention, we use NULL, not 0, to represent orphans.

Comment: If so, i have to change type of the column from int() to string. Is it correct, considering that it contains ids, which are numbers? Nevertheless, it's not such a big deal, especially compared to my main problem with comparings values)

Comment: Yeh, you were right. My mistake — i don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a select such that you can have a t/f flag.

```
SELECT 
  p.id, p.nParentID,p.sTitle,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pub.category c WHERE c.nParentId = p.id) AS nChildrenCount,
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  pub.category c WHERE c.nParentId = p.id) , true, false) AS bHasChildren
FROM pub.category p
```

I've included a count as well for clarity.

However, if you are trying to make cascading menus, you are going to find this flag might be handy but you really need a ui side/ middleware side recursive function to build your menu into a nice relational object for you. The flag could be used by the recursive menu builder.

Comment: I'll definitely have no more than 1 child level in each category, so i didn't want to overcomplicate without real need.